# How to select a specific subsystem on WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hello I have the following installations on my WSL.
I want to 1)select and 2) update the following subsystem: Ubuntu-18.04
[image]

Update:

1. I can run
   `wsl -s Ubuntu-18.04` to select some release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-d/--distribution <distroname>` option to run a particular instance.  So `wsl -d Ubuntu-18.04` will start that distribution and allow you to update.  Better yet (and undocumented), `wsl ~ -d Ubuntu-18.04`, since that will start you in your home directory.

The `-s` that you mentioned is short for `--select-default`.  This changes the default instance so that the next time you run `wsl` without a `-d/--distribution` option, the default runs.

There are quite a few useful options [documented here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference), starting with `-h/--help` which will give you a short overview in the console.

Also, for updating the instance, you can do it in a one-liner with:

```
wsl -d Ubuntu-18.04 -u root sh -c "apt update && apt upgrade"
```